# Running Selenium tests serially on multiple machines

Tags: selenium

I am writing test automation for a web app.  One of the supported capabilities of the product which I need to test is the following.  Different users can be logged in on different machines at the same time, and when User 1 enters some data on Machine 1, the view for User 2 on Machine 2 automatically gets updated with that data, in real time, without needing to reload their browser.

In researching this, I have seen mentioned the tool Selenium Grid.  From what I've read, that seems to be a parallelization / distribution tool, where a test suite can be distributed across multiple machines.  This is close to what I need, in that multiple machines are controlled, but I need to be able to choose which machine runs which actions, and in what order and at what time.

The questions are:

1. Is this scenario something which Selenium Grid would work for?
2. If not, is there another approach I should investigate?

Comment: Quick though of an alternative - Can you use 2 private/incognito sessions on the same computer? Those 2 windows will not share state and will only receive information from the server. Using grid would add to complication

Comment: Good idea.  Dev had originally told me that wouldn't work, but apparently they changed something so it will now.  Thankee.